# Getting the org.eclipse.ocl bundle to work in in Apache Felix

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I think I already know the answer to this, but it's important so I need to be sure.  Maybe there's some trick.

It is possible to run the bundle org.eclipse.ocl-3.3.0 in an Apache Felix container?

The bundle in question depends on org.eclipse.runtime, and org.eclipse.osgi.

Deploy the above to Felix and nothing works.  Deploy them to equinox and all is well, but then other bundles break.  This has been a nasty surprise. I have a feeling I'm screwed and on the verge of regretting I ever took a step down the OSGi path.  But I though I'd ask this good community in a last ditch effort.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If this bundle as a "Require-Bundle" dependency on bundles that you cannot install in any other container but Equinox (because they're part of Equinox' system bundle for example), then yes, this bundle was designed to only run on Equinox.

You cannot blame OSGi for the fact that someone made a (probably) poor design choice when creating his bundle. To offer some constructive advice, reach out to the community that built this bundle, discuss this with them. Maybe they are willing to change this, or offer some advice on how you can modify this bundle so it does work in other frameworks.

Comment: Yes. Ask the bundle developer to replace the Require-Bundle with the equivalent set of Import-Packages. It is quite likely the bundle does not actually need the Equinox framework. The developer rather took the shortcut of Require-Bundle.